# spring transaction commits but data not inserted in db

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am facing an issue in my application which uses spring 3.1 & hibernate 3.6.
 
I have two service classes ServiceA & ServiceB. ServiceB.dbInsert() method has 'REQUIRES_NEW' tx attribute and ServiceA has 'REQUIRED' at the class level.
1. when i execute normally - the data inserted by ServiceB.dbInsert() is commited to DB - THIS IS FINE.
2. when i fail the tx of ServiceB.dbInsert() using debug mode in eclipse, the Tx is rolled back - THIS IS FINE.
3. In case 2 above, if i retry the operation i.e. call ServiceB.dbInsert() from ServiceA after failure , the data inserted by ServiceB.dbInsert() is NOT commited. - THIS IS A PROBLEM.

In all the above cases the Spring Transaction Advice is applied and the spring's doCommit() is called (except in case 2 where rollback happens). 

It is not clear why CASE 3 is having the issue. There is no exception thrown. Have checked thoroughly in debug mode.

Comment: Couldn't it be a problem of hibernate marking the whole session as rollback only ?

Comment: Doesn't seem so as in the debug mode I can see the commit code of the spring Tx advise being called instead of its rollback code.

Comment: Can you add the examples of your class? in order to make clear this question. At first glance seems that spring proxy does not works fine, but is strange.